# How to use DDNS with scada systems that does not support domain names

Tags: ip, dns

We have a SCADA system that needed to pool stations via fixed IP addresses.
Our station does not assign fixed IP, so we would like to use DDNS to resolve this issue.
However the SCADA system does not support entering domain name in its GUI! It just manages IP addresses.

My question is how we can use the SCADA system with DDNS?

Comment: If there's no option for domain name, I *seriously* doubt there are any for DDNS.

Comment: @RickyBeam, how about reverse DDNS?

Comment: Do you know what DDNS is? (dynamic dns) If the system requires an IP address, it *requires* an IP address. No amount of trying to stuff a hostname in there will matter.

Comment: Could you specify which SCADA system you are talking of and if this one is working on IP or not?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before looking at your addressing plan managment through DDNS, I advise you to look at something much more traditionnal and which works with sone SCADA networks:

1. Configure a DHCP server on your SCADA supervision server or on a completly independant server dedicated to the adressing plan managment and the static IP broadcasting.
2. Collect all the @MAC of your SCADA clients and enter them within the DHCP configuration file.

Next, if you want to differientate different classes of SCADA clients through names, I suggest you start up on the same addressing plan managment server a DNS server so as to be able to name clients through names like:

```
02-RC.ddc-4000.scada.mydomain
```

Answer (score 0):

Stations are connected to internal network or into a public network?

a) Internal network: just configure your DHCP server to assign fixed IP address to station by binding a specific IP to the MAC of your station.

b) Public network: If the station is connected to public network through a router you should check if you can establish a site2site VPN. Is possible that you have to configure a different network for each station.